# How to input a string or a sentence and output the corresponding value(s) from the dictionary

Tags: python

I am able to print the key:value combinations when I do print(d). Now my objective is that when I input a message in im eg. y r u late. It should print back why are you late. The aim is to split the sentence into words and replace it by the associated text value if available otherwise keep the original word

This is for a school assignment and I am just looking for some help on this

This is what a part of my dictionary looks like:

```
{'r': 'are\n', 'y': 'why\n', 'u': 'you\n', 'ttyl': 'talk to you later\n', 'l8': 'late\n', 'brb': 'be right back\n', 'lol': 'laughing out loud\n', 'bbl': 'be back later\n', 'tldr': "too long; didn't read\n", 'rofl': 'rolling on floor laughing\n', 'gtg': 'got to go\n'}
```

```
d = {}
with open("abbreviations.txt") as abb:
    for line in abb:
        (key, val) = line.split(":")
        d[key] = val

print(d)

im = input("Enter message here: ")
```

Comment: add this by the end of the script `reason = d.get(im,'no idea why..')
print(reason)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are for sure more compact ways to do it but this should help you understand and explore more while coding.

What you should know is that you can use the `dict.get(<key>)` method from a dictionary to retrieve the value. In case this is not present it will return `None`

```
d = {}
with open("abbreviations.txt") as abb:
    for line in abb:
        (key, val) = line.split(":")
        d[key] = val

print(d)

im = input("Enter message here: ")

final_prhase = ""

for abb in im.split():
    temp = d.get(abb) or abb
    final_prhase += "{} ".format(temp)

print("Your are saying: {}".format(final_prhase))
```

Comment: You are missing spaces between the words in your final_phrase. Also I don't think the input message is expected to consist of only abbreviations.

Comment: You are right on the spaces but I don't know how @baldeman  expect the input. I followed his request and provided another example then he can choose what to do. Let me add your suggestion to my code anyway. Thank you

Comment: Nothing wrong with options to choose from. However, @Malan clearly states that words, that don't appear in the dictionary should just be taken as they are. In your solution they would be missing.

Comment: Silly me, my bad. Fixed now

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
d = {}
with open("abbreviations.txt") as abb:
    for line in abb:
        (key, val) = line.split(":")
        d[key] = val

print(d)

im = input("Enter message here: ")
message = ' '.join([d[s] if s in d else s for s in im.split()])
```